# how do you start webdriver-manager start in the Config file

Tags: angularjs, selenium, testing, protractor, webdriver-manager

I'm trying to get my config file to the point where I don't have to go to the mac terminal and type **webdriver-manager start**. Is it possible to have the config file do that? I have listed my code below to give you idea what I have set up. I just don't know if it is possible. Let me know. I am on a macbook pro.

```
exports.config = {

    seleniumServerJar: './selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.45.1.jar',

    seleniumPort: null,

    chromeDriver: './selenium/chromedriver.exe',
    chromeDriver: null,


    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',


    // ----- What tests to run -----

    suites: {
        CSRSmokeTest: '../smoke/deskTop/CSR.js'
        DesktopSmokeTest: '../smoke/deskTop/**.js'
    },

    chromeOnly: false,

    multiCapabilities: [
        {
            'browserName': 'chrome',
            'chromeOptions': {
                args: ['--lang=en',
                    '--window-size=1900,1200']
            }
        },

    ],

    baseUrl: location + '/login/#/login',
    rootElement: 'body',

    onPrepare: function () {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        browser.get(location + '/login/#/login');
    },
    params: {
        user: {

            //TEST******************************************


        },
        url: {

            //some code

        }

    },

    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        // onComplete will be called just before the driver quits.
        onComplete: null,
        // If true, display spec names.
        isVerbose: true,
        // If true, print colors to the terminal.
        showColors: true,
        // If true, include stack traces in failures.
        includeStackTrace: true,
        // Default time to wait in ms before a test fails.
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 6000000
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just do not want to type in terminal you have several options:

1. Leave only `seleniumServerJar` option, and remove `seleniumAddress`. But starting Selenium everytime takes additionally 5-20 sec (depending on the hardware).
2. Use `directConnect: true` for Chrome. And then you do not need Selenium server at all. It works for me, but it is not fully portable solution.
3. Install Selenium somewhere on your server and leave it running forever. In this case your application should have publically accessible URL, so not just localhost.

Comment: You want to know something been trying to do that all day yesterday and I just needed to put the chromedriver.exe in the correct folder. Thank you.